# Hot water bath and Infertility

Tags: reproduction

From [here](http://www.uwyo.edu/wjm/repro/spermat.htm):

> Effect of temperature. Sperm cells will not mature at core body temperature in most mammals (spermatogenic DNA polymerase b and recombinase activities exhibit unique temperature optima); to adapt, the testes assume an external position. Testicular descent from the abdomen normally transpires during fetal or neonatal life.
>
> If the testes fail to descend into the scrotum, a condition called cryptorchidism, the male will be sterile; gone uncorrected (by surgery or androgen treatment) spermatogonia will eventually degenerate.

1. How many minutes of exposure to hot water is tolerable?
2. Can regularly bathing in hot water lead to infertility?
3. Up to what temperature (of bath water - assuming the maximum tolerable temperature would not hurt skin) is tolerable?